# The meaning of the 'enclosure' word

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

I can't understand the meaning of the word 'enclosure' in the context: "This client reads one or more RSS feeds, queues up the enclosures for download, and processes several downloads in parallel using threads.". Can you explain me please the meaning of it.

I read it in the python docs - https://pymotw.com/2/Queue/#using-queues-with-threads

Comment: The analogy is to an old-fashioned "snail mail" letter:  In addition to the letter itself you might have several "enclosures" -- additional pages that are not part of the letter but are information the recipient might want to refer to while/after reading the letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, *enclosure* means more-or-less what it sounds like: something that is enclosed in something else.  It usually referred to anything included in a letter or package.  If you put a lock of hair in a love-note, the hair would be the enclosure.

In your example, it is a *[term of art](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/term_of_art)* specific to the [definition of an RSS feed](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/xml/rss/feeds/index.html).  An enclosure is a media-item (such as an image or a video) sent along with an entry in the feed.

Comment: Thank you for response, Malvolio. It helps me. I haven't enough rating to vote up your answer.

Comment: @discort -- we don't do it for the fame.  You are quite welcome.

Comment: @discort - I've given an upvote on your behalf!